Magento 2.4.6-p6 | Indexer killed
So after setting up a new Magento Installation and adding all the products, catalogrules and everything needed the indexer doesnt run like expected.
When doing ìndexer:reset && indexer:reindex via the CLI after some time i get the following output in the CLI:
Catalog Rule Product index Killed

Server Specs
PHP MEMORY: 8GB (more available)
EXECUTION TIME: 18000
Products in Shop: ~200k
Catalogrules: ~40
Is there any way or patch to resolve this issue?

If you are running on Linux the most probable issue is the OOM killer. This is a process on the kernel that when the total memory is reached, will select a process that consumes a lot of memory and kill it. See https://sematext.com/glossary/linux-out-of-memory-killer/
To avoid this, make sure you have enough memory or have the swap enabled into the system.
Does not matter how much to put up the memory on PHP, if the system does not have free memory will be tackled by OOM killer.
